# Bandwidth Quota for Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, quota

This morning we got a couple of errors from Google Apps script saying:

```
Exception: Bandwidth quota exceeded...
Try reducing the rate of data transfer.
```

Our Google Apps Script (GAS) programs mainly look at Gmail, do some processing, access Google Maps some, and transfer data back and forth between GAS/GCP and an app hosted on another platform.

However, accessing Gmail doesn't seem to be what this is talking about.  "Bandwidth quota" would seem to indicate too much data is being transferred into and out of the Google servers via Google Apps Script.  We do transfer a fair amount of data back and forth to an app hosted on another platform on the Internet, such as Amazon Web Services.

However, we don't see that there is a "Bandwidth quota" on the [Google Services Quotas page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).  AND around the time we got this error this morning, we weren't accessing Gmail nor transferring data back and forth outside of GCP any more than usual.  Probably less.

Does anyone know what this quota is, where we can find it, and how we can possibly bump it up, even if we need to pay for it?

I looked at our Google Cloud Platform (CCP) Console Quotas (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) and we are well below any usage limit, and see none that are about a "Bandwidth Quota".

Thank you!

UPDATE 29 March 2022 - After more than a month of having zero of these messages, this evening we are seeing at least 10 of them.  Some facts:

- The "bandwidth quota exceeded" errors are only happening when calling the APIs for one particular external app hosted on AWS-like servers.  They do not occur when calling drive, maps, etc. or any other APIs.
- Today has been a lower-volume day & evening for our app than many are.  So, this makes no sense why we would get these errors this evening and not other days.

Comment: Please add more details, if possible add a [mcve].

Comment: Is your AppScript project using an specific service like Drive or Gmail? The project may be leading to one of the specific services quotas, sharing more details about what the script is doing would be useful in this scenario.

Comment: @Rubén good question.  I edited the question above to give more detail.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo good question.  I edited the question above to give more detail.

Comment: My guess is that like it says you sending to much data to quickly.  You get instantaneous errors without exceeding you daily total and they can result in errors.  So that what the message is suggesting to reduce the rate of data transfer.  Without the code we can't help you any more than that but if there is too much code we may not wish to help.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you.  Yes, there is too much code.  However, this morning there was no more data transfer than usual.  Actually, probably less, and we've never seen this error before.  Further, where is this quota defined?  I haven't seen it anywhere.  On the Quotas page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas, there is nothing about a "Bandwidth" quota or limitation.

Comment: Date xfer errors in my experience are often resolved by reducing the data xfer rate.  If you don't wish to do that that's okay with me.  I'm not getting the errors.

Comment: @Chris I have also faced exactly the same error with my code to fetch data into Google sheet via few external API requests and that happened yesterday only two times out of the many times of the day that those requests are being sent. We already have delays introduced in code for API rate limits.

It has gone quite after that and it seems that Google is experimenting something at the back end as apparently this kind of error does not seem to be there in any of the quota defining references.

Comment: @FiTeach I tend to agree with you.  There is nothing about this in the quotas and it hasn't happened for us since, but could be that volumes have been down a bit.  I'm guessing that you are correct and/or over the last couple of years we have seen Google Apps Script with GCP have a number of problems with errors on their servers.  I've documented these online and a number of others saw the same things with errors, sometimes extremely significant errors not allowing GAS to work for hours.  I'm guessing they either had some errors or are experimenting like you said.

Comment: Please see an update from today above in my original post.

Comment: @Chris, saw this for the first time today.  Occurred when virtually no traffic and with the same call that we make every 10 minutes for months now.  Same call working fine now.  Seems to me to be an error on the backend as there is nothing that we can change here.

Comment: I'm seeing similar and have filed a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228237163